# How do I read the property values of a JSON error object using Combine in Swift?

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

All of my API endpoints return a response which looks something like this in Postman:

```
{
    "statusCode": 401,
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "Missing authentication"
}
```

What I would like to do is make the request, and have access to these properties in Swift. There will be some cases where I use the error message property's value in the front of the app. This will be determined by the statusCode returned.

What I have right now is this:

```
    private var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
    let url = URL(string: "http://abc336699.com/create")
    self.cancellable = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url!)
      .map { $0.data }
```

Prior to this, I tried tryMap, but the type of error it returned didn't give me the flexibility I wanted. I then moved on and tried Almofire, but it seemed like an over kill for what I want to do.

I wanted to check what is being returned in the response I get, but I get the following error:

```
Cannot assign value of type 'Publishers.Map<URLSession.DataTaskPublisher, Data>' to type 'AnyCancellable'
```

I want simple access to my response errors so I can integrate the API throughout the app using combine.

Comment: `AnyCancellable` is a protocol typically implemented by subscribers to a publisher, like the ones used in `.sink` or `.assign`. `.map` is another publisher (not a subscriber). You can use `.catch` if you need to handle an error

Comment: Why are you not creating a decodable model based on your JSON response and decode it using the decode operator in Combine?

Comment: @user832 That's fine if there's data to decode after a 200 statusCode response, but I need to catch errors too.

Comment: @LondonGuy, this should help you: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/processing_url_session_data_task_results_with_combine

Comment: @LondonGuy keep in mind that a non-200 status count is a networking success. The data task publisher will only error if the request never got a response from the server. If the server returns a non-200 status code you can extract that in your `map`

Comment: @donnywals I found a way to handle it using sink. First I created a struct to represent my error object, then I decoded it before using sink. I wrote code to detect the status codes inside "receive value". Works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure from where you will be getting your data as in JSON response there is no Key for data. Before writing below code my understanding was that you want to check `error` and `statusCode` from the mentioned JSON response and then move forward with your business logic. The below code is to give you a vague idea of how we can do that.

```
    enum CustomError: Error {

    case custom(_ error: String)
    case unknownStatusCode
    case errorOccurred
}

let url = URL(string: "http://abc336699.com/create")

    func load() -> AnyPublisher<Data,CustomError> {
    URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url!)
        .map(\.data)
        .tryMap { (data) -> Data in
            let genericModel = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: AnyObject]

            if let statusCode = genericModel?["statusCode"] as? String {
                switch statusCode {
                case "200":
                    guard let data = genericModel?["message"] as? Data else {
                        throw CustomError.custom("Parsing error")
                    }
                    return data
                default:
                    if let error = genericModel?["error"] as? String {
                        throw CustomError.custom(error)
                    } else {
                        throw CustomError.unknownError
                    }
                }
            }
            throw CustomError.errorOccurred
    }
    .decode(type: YourCustomDecodableModel.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
    .mapError({ $0 as? CustomError ?? CustomError.errorOccurred })
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Comment: How it works is, if the status code is not 200, the object in my question will show, if the status code is 200, the same object will show, but the status code will be 200, the error will be "Success" and the message will be the data e.g. a list of names or something.

Comment: @LondonGuy I have updated the load method based on your comment

Comment: This led me to my answer which I found on: https://heckj.github.io/swiftui-notes/#reasoning-about-pipelines