# Casting JSON list of objects for NSBatchInsertRequest to [[String:Any]] fails

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, combine, batch-insert

I have [a small project at Github](https://github.com/afarber/ios-questions/tree/master/Tops1) which downloads [a JSON list of objects](https://slova.de/ws/top), parses it and stores in Core Data:

[image: screenshot]

In the [view model](https://github.com/afarber/ios-questions/blob/master/Tops1/Tops1/ViewModels/TopViewModel.swift) I just iterate through the JSON list, create Core Data entities and then save the context:

```
URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
    .tryMap(handleOutput)
    .decode(type: TopResponse.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
    .sink { completion in
        print("fetchTopModels completion=\(completion)")
    } receiveValue: { fetchedTops in
        PersistenceController.shared.container.performBackgroundTask { backgroundContext in
            backgroundContext.mergePolicy = NSMergePolicy.mergeByPropertyObjectTrump
            backgroundContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
            backgroundContext.perform {
                for topModel in fetchedTops.data {
                    let topEntity = TopEntity(context: backgroundContext)
                    topEntity.language = language
                    topEntity.uid = Int32(topModel.id)
                    // etc.
                }
                if (backgroundContext.hasChanges) {
                    do {
                        try backgroundContext.save()
```

This works well, but is very slow when I have a list with 100000 objects.

So I have decided to create [another small project at Github](https://github.com/afarber/ios-questions/tree/master/TopsBatchInsert), which uses [NSBatchInsertRequest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsbatchinsertrequest).

And being a Swift newbie I already fail at the very first step :-)

I was thinking of casting the [TopResponse.data](https://github.com/afarber/ios-questions/blob/master/TopsBatchInsert/TopsBatchInsert/Models/TopModel.swift) to `[[String:Any]]`

```
struct TopResponse: Codable {
    let data: [TopModel]
}

struct TopModel: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: Int { uid }
    let uid: Int
    // etc.
}
```

So in [the new view model](https://github.com/afarber/ios-questions/blob/master/TopsBatchInsert/TopsBatchInsert/ViewModels/TopViewModel.swift) I have tried the code:

```
URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
    .tryMap(handleOutput)
    .decode(type: TopResponse.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
    .sink { completion in
        print("fetchTopModels completion=\(completion)")
    } receiveValue: { topResponse in
        guard let fetchedTops = topResponse.data as? [[String: Any]] else { return }
        PersistenceController.shared.container.performBackgroundTask { backgroundContext in
            backgroundContext.mergePolicy = NSMergePolicy.mergeByPropertyObjectTrump
            backgroundContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
            backgroundContext.perform {
                
                let batchInsert = NSBatchInsertRequest(entity: TopEntity.entity(), objects: fetchedTops)

                do {
                    try backgroundContext.execute(batchInsert)
```

but the casting fails and I see in debugger that `fetchedTops` has zero elements:

[image: Xcode screenshot]

Why is it happening? I was expecting the JSON list of objects to be casted perfectly to a `[[String:Any]]`

Comment: Because you already transformed it into `TopResponse`. You used `.decode(type: TopResponse.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())` , for what? To transform the response `Data` object into `TopResponse`, so it's an instance of `TopResponse`.

Comment: Ok thanks (upvoted) and how to transform the JSON list of objects into something edible for the `NSBatchInsertRequest` call?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `Publisher`, but I'd remove `.decode(type: TopResponse.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())`, maybe letting `topResponse` to be `Data` and call `JSONSerialization` on it in order to has `[[String: Any]]` at some point. Either that, or either the publisher has a similar solution for it like `decode(type:decoder:)`. Why? You already did `Data` -> `TopResponse`, it would be strange to go back from `TopResponse` to `Dictionary/Array`, no?

Comment: There is a sample code https://stackoverflow.com/a/62079390/1801544 to call `JSONSerialization` on result data...